# Communication between microcontroller and separately powered PCB (electronics)

Tags: communication, microcontroller

On one board I have a microcontroller with one power supply and on another I have a Flip Flop with a separate power supply. I want to connect a pin of the microcontroller to the reset pin of the flip flop. Can I just put a wire accross or does it need more than that? I was going to do that but now I'm not sure that would work because it wouldn't be a complete circuit and the two boards may not have quite the same ground levels.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use the same power supply for both?

Comment: ask here http://chiphacker.com/

Comment: Not really programming related. But an optocoupler would fix it. (edit: as Carl said below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If for some reason you can't have a common ground, you could look into [optoisolators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opto-isolator).